# How to get the stderr of the latest failed step in Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

While working with Github actions, I need to understand what would I need to do in order to capture the log lines when there is an error in any step and in a following job, send those to an external system.

Let's set the next scenario:

```
jobs:
  job1:
    name: job 1
    steps:
      - name: step1
      ...
      - name: step2
      ...
      - name: step3
      ...
    ...
  job2:
    name: job 2
    needs: [job1]
    if: always()
    steps:
      - name: Send error lines to third party system
    ...
```

During the execution of job1, one of the steps fail, consequently setting some error logs in the stdout and stderr.

---

What would be the way to capture those errored log lines in job2, in order to take some actions with them? Such as sending those to an external system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I've addressed a similar need is to use `tee`:

```yaml
    steps:
      - name: Run Tool
        run: |
          some_tool | tee output.log
        shell: bash
```

That results in you getting the same logs you'd always see in the GitHub Actions console, while also persisting them to disk. If you want stderr too, do

```bash
some_tool 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

Then, in a later step in the same job, you can do whatever you like with those logs, using the [`if: ${{ failure() }}` syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#failure):

```yaml
    steps:
      - name: Persist logs
        if: ${{ failure() }}
        run: |
          cat output.log | do_something_with_logs
        shell: bash
```

If you need to persist the logs across a job boundary, you could use [artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts).

Comment: One of the cleanest solutions I saw, thank you.
I guess that Github Actions doesn't provide a built-in way of handling errors across jobs... Do you know? I wanted to avoid custom solutions, however, I believe one solution like this is the cleanest we could make.

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-features for that, no, but there could be something new that I'm missing!

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't help for `use` steps since we can't use the tee command. I'm still looking for a solution to this.

Comment: @tvandinther Well-written actions should handle their own errors and return results in Github Actions outputs. If open source, you could update an action to do that. If not, contact the author (pointing to this solution), I'm sure they will be happy to enhance their action.